# Which Xbox 360 games have free avatar accessory awards?

Tags: xbox-360

ilomilo offers free T-Shirts for your avatar if you unlock certain achievements (in the full game). Are there any other games (arcade, indie or full), that offer bonus avatar accessories with no extra expenditure of MS points?

Comment: Halo: Reach, Fable 3, Perfect Dark (XBLA) come to mind. edit: Apparently all "recent" games come with this feature (just a quick web search). Don't have a reliable source so I'm not submitting as an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, since it falls under *Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)*, which is now off-topic, as outlined in our [FAQ]. This was the result of the identify-this-game debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xbox Resource](http://www.xboxresource.com/avatars.php?text=true&filter=awards&type=default) has an up to date list as well that can be filtered and sorted and will show you all the different awards per game.  I do not know if the list is complete but it seems to match up with what I have seen, and awards I have received.

Also, I do not believe that all recent games come with free awards just seen by what I've played recently (Bulletstorm, Dead Space 2, Fallout: New Vegas). It is also more common to find awards in XBLA games for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Free Xbox Avatars](http://www.freexboxavatars.com/). It doesn't have everything, but you can start looking here.